# count distinct window function Databricks

Tags: mysql, sql, apache-spark-sql, databricks, window-functions

I am implementing count distinct window functions in Databricks.

`select *,count(distinct Marks) over(partition by Name) from data`

It seems that count distinct is not supported in Databricks, how can I replicate the same query in databricks.

Comment: Can you add some more information on what are you trying to do here with table details,  some sample data and expected results?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `collect_set` + `size` functions:

```sql
select *, size(collect_set(Marks) over(partition by Name)) from data
```